# Calculate Laplace transform of the product of t and f(t) by differentiating f(t) (5.5-6)

Tags: derivatives, laplace-transform, solution-verification

**Request**:

Please check my work. State where errors, if any, occurred and how to correct them. Is there a better way to calculate the transform other than the present method given?

**Given**:

Find the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}\{t^2\cdot \sinh(2t)\}$ by differentiating $f(t)$.

**Solution**:

$$\mathcal{L}\{t\cdot f(t)\}=-F'(s)$$

$$\mathcal{L}\{t^2\cdot f(t)\}=F''(s)$$

$$f(t)=\sinh(2t)$$

$$F(s)=\frac{2}{s^2-4}$$

$$F'(s)=\frac{-1\cdot 2s\cdot 2}{(s^2-4)^2}=-\frac{4s}{(s^2-4)^2}$$

$$F''(s)=-\frac{4}{(s^2-4)^2}-\frac{-2\cdot 2s\cdot4s}{(s^2-4)^3}=-\frac{4}{(s^2-4)^2}+\frac{16s^2}{(s^2-4)^3}$$

**Answer**:

$$\mathcal{L}\{t^2\cdot \sinh(2t)\}=F''(s)=-\frac{4}{(s^2-4)^2}+\frac{16s^2}{(s^2-4)^3}$$

I also claim that for even powers of $t^n$ there is no need change the sign of the derivative because they cancel out. Is this a good assumption?

Comment: The problem is your derivatives. No negative sign on the $16$.

Comment: Here is what you should get $$ 4\,{\frac {3\,{s}^{2}+4}{ \left( s^2-4 \right) ^{3}}}.$$

Comment: Thank you for coming through for me again, Dustin.

Comment: No worries, it wasn't an issue to do so at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what happens with the derivatives, let's look at the definition of the Laplace transform of a generic function of $t^n\sinh(bt)$.
$$
\mathcal{L}\{t^n\sinh(bt)\} = \int_0^{\infty}t^n\sinh(bt)e^{-st}dt = 
\frac{\partial^n}{\partial s^n}(-1)^n\int_0^{\infty}\sinh(bt)e^{-st}dt = \frac{\partial^n}{\partial s^n}(-1)^n\mathcal{L}\{\sinh(bt)\}
$$
Since we are taking the derivative of $e^{-st}$, we pick up a negative for every derivative. Now, as you claim, for even derivatives, we have a positive. That is due to $(-1)(-1)\cdots (-1)$ an even number of times which gives back $1$. Therefore, for odd derivatives, we would pick up a negative.